# Implement TCP/UDP Port in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, udp, tcplistener

We want to implement a port over Windows Azure Cloud Service and would like some feedback on our strategy.

Our current Project:

- **Physical GPS unit** that runs as an *client*.
- **Windows Azure Cloud Service** that runs as an *server*.

1)Physical GPS unit: 
    We are using XT-4000[Xirgo Technologies] physical Gps unit which is a powerful tracking, monitoring and control gateway device.This device requires UDP or TCP port to communicate.

2)Windows Azure Cloud Service:
    Here we need to open up a TCP or UDP port and have a listener there and listen for incoming data which is pushed by the device[XT-4000].

Here's what we are thinking our strategy should be. All advice is appreciated.

- Creating TCP port on Azure.
- Set the listener for receiving incoming signals from device.

**[But the question is can we create TCP port on Windows Azure Cloud Service as its a cloud based platform and if yes , then how ?]**

*Two additional questions:*

- As the device supports both UDP or TCP port to communicate, which one is better?
- For receiving Signals from device to port do we need any third party help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Windows Azure Cloud Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/cloud-services/) and not [Windows Azure Web Site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/).

For the cloud service you will need to use a Worker Role to implement the protocol supported by the device. You can either TCP or UDP - whatever you are more comfortable programming with. You will have to [define an input endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh369931.aspx) for your cloud service.

As for the additional questions:

```
As the device supports both UDP or TCP port to communicate, which one is better?
```

Depends on the protocol supported by the device. I've seen numerous protocols used by GPS devices. Ranging from "just send and forget" to "very robust error checking and receive confirmation". If your device's protocol is of type "just send and forget", probably TCP is better as it is more reliable. If the device's protocol is error-prone and does validation/CRC-Check/receive confirmation, then you are OK to go with UDP.

> For receiving Signals from device to port do we need any third party
>   help ?

This depends on your programming skills ...

Comment: Thanks for your guide lines astaykov.

Comment: @astaykov i don't understand why a "just send and forget" should use TCP, this is basically the definition of an UDP protocol. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @Crypth why you ask me?! Ask the guys who produce these kind of devices! But I am pretty happy with such implementation anyway. Azure didn't have support for UDP for quite a long time, and I was happily running "fire and forget" type devices over TCP. I wonder what is the driver behind commenting an 8 months old post without even knowing the market of GPS devices (apparently)!

Comment: @astaykov Well, i chose EC2 over Azure some time ago, and read up on Azure now that is has UDP support and got interested as i work with real time systems over UDP. I clearly misunderstood your answer then, as UDP is the common usage for fire and forget communication but clearly my ignorance about GPS systems got in the way of understanding. My bad and sorry for asking.

Answer (score 3):

We have implemented a similar service (vehicle tracking) running successfully on Windows Azure. Some observations:

- As per astakov's answer, you are looking at a cloud service (worker role)
- Azure supports both TCP and UDP, but if you have a choice, go for TCP. UDP does not have connections and the device has no way of knowing whether or not your service has received the data. We were forced to use UDP and have to send acknowledgement data to the device, otherwise it gets resent (we effectively had to write our own protocol over UDP). Sending UDP packets from your server to the device may get blocked by mobile network firewall rules (and other network configuration). Fight against UDP as much as possible — the lossy nature of UDP is totally unsuitable to vehicle tracking.
- Check on whether or not the device supports DNS. Many of these devices only send to IP addresses, which makes deployment a bit tricker.
- These devices need to minimise data transmitted (because of GSM data costs) and usually send data in a proprietary and compressed format. Most of your effort is going to be spent picking apart binary data. If you can, find a supplier that has a library that you can use server-side to decode the data. I our particular case (for a custom designed and built device) it took about 10 man months of development just to decode the data properly.

Comment: I wouldn't say deployment is by any way trickier if device does not support DNS. Windows Azure Guarantees IP address will not change as long as there is deployment and you **do not delete** it. There is absolutely no difference in how you deploy your cloud service with respect to whether device supports DNS or not. Nowadays all kind of in-place upgrades are supported.